# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'then' in IE11 in AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error in IE: "**TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'**", in the following function called in my AngularJs controller:

```
GetUserAccessService.checkForValidHashPeriod()
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result === 'false') {
            GetUserAccessService.returnUserHashAuthentication();
        }
    });
```

This is the `GetUserAccessService.checkForValidHashPeriod` function called in my AngularJs service:

```
this.checkForValidHashPeriod = function () {
    var result;
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if ($sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate !== null && $sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate !== undefined) {
        var timeDiff = now - $sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate;
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined($sessionStorage.userAuthenticationToken) || timeDiff > 1500000) {
        result = false;
    }
    else {
        result = true;
    }
    var stringResult = result.toString();
    return stringResult;
};
```

What am I doing wrong by using a `.then` call?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in your code to suggest the `stringResult` returned from `checkForValidHashPeriod` would have a `then` method. As far as I can tell, it will only ever be the string value `"true"` or `"false"`

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your response. May I ask that you clarify what you mean with "nothing in your code to suggest the `stringResult` returned from `checkForValidHashPeriod` would have a `then` method". I am learning and would like to understand.

Comment: Your method returns a string, not a promise. Strings do **not** have a `then` method ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods

Comment: @Phil Thank you! Geeze i wish I had known that a couple weeks ago. Not everybody gives explanations why something is wrong. You often get down voted for asking a valid question. But as it is perceived to be s 'stupid' question (or answer) by someone, you are penalized. Anyway, that is why we come to StackOverflow; to learn and grow and give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call below has to be changed as your method will be returning a string and can't use 'then' here

```
Var someString = GetUserAccessService.checkForValidHashPeriod()
    if (someString === 'false') {
        GetUserAccessService.returnUserHashAuthentication();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and input :D

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to use promises with IE, you can try to use the bluebird lib that handle compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: OP is not using promises. Also, Angular comes with the `$q` service which supports IE9+ ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Answer (score -1):

In case someone else has the same issue, here is an alternate answer (also, this is the method I ended up using), based on the comments and help from Phil:

```
this.checkForValidHashPeriod = function () {
    var result = $q.defer();
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if ($sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate !== null && $sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate !== undefined) {
        var timeDiff = now - $sessionStorage.userAuthenticationTokenDate;
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined($sessionStorage.userAuthenticationToken) || timeDiff > 1500000) {
        result.resolve(false);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Hash is valid.')
        result.resolve(true);
    }
    return result.promise;
};
```

Yes, I know it is perhaps an unnecessary use of `promises` and `$q`, but I like the method, and is inline with the rest of my service.

Comment: Why are you returning a promise? There is no asynchronous task here at all.

Comment: @Phil Can you perhaps be more helpful instead of down voting? You keep telling me what I am not doing, but you do not offer any real insight or help. Honestly; I come here to learn.

Comment: You should read documentation to learn, this is a Q/A site. I suggest you start at [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and pay particular attention to the _"See also"_ section at the end. In a nutshell, promises help overcome the problem of asynchronous computation. Your code has no asynchronous computation and thus does not need to use promises / deferred objects. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43317239/283366) is the best example of what you should be doing with the code in your question

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the response. I know it is a Q/A site, but more often than not people offer insight to assist those whom ask the question, with understanding their issue. That beside; the reason I added the `$q` and `promise` to `checkForValidHashPeriod` was for the asynchronous function call of this service (`GetUserAccessService.checkForValidHashPeriod`), that has the `.then` method. Refer to my original question. Is this wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: It's not specifically *wrong* (as in you won't get an error) but it's completely needless